# How to enable vIOMMU in virt-manager?

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am planning to perform nested virtualization with GPU device. I have guest Ubuntu OS running and I have mapped GPU to it by enabling `intel_iommu` on the host, and configuring NVIDIA PCI as `vfio-pci` device. I am also able to install NVIDIA driver on the guest and use it for deep-learning.

However, now I want to run another VM inside the guest, let's call the guest that runs on host as L1 and the guest  that runs on guest as L2, I want the GPU to be accessiable by the L2 guest, I came across `vIOMMU` supported on Q35 Qemu chipset, how do I enable IOMMU on L1 guest, so that I can pass the gpu directly to L2 guest??

Answer (score 1):

virt-manager, as a simple graphical interface, does not support many advanced features of the underlying virtualization platform.

To do what you want, you need to tap into [`libvirt`](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html) or even custom `qemu` command line options.